# Spring Boot POST gives me a 404 error and I don't know why

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm currently working on a project with Spring Boot and when I try to POST a new object, a 404 error comes up. I don't know why because when I try the POST with httpie on this link it works. I'm working with Spring Boot, PostgresSQL (PGAdmin) and Thymeleaf.

This is my `@Controller` class:

```
@RequestMapping("/Mitarbeiter")
public String alleMitarbeiterAnzeigen(Model m)
{
    m.addAttribute("AlleMitarbeiter", mitarbeiterRepository.findAll());
    return "showMitarbeiter";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/neuerMitarbeiter")
public String neuerMitarbeiter(Model m)
{
    m.addAttribute("mitarbeiter", new Mitarbeiter());
    return "neuerMitarbeiter";
}

@PostMapping(value="/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen")
public String neuenMitarbeiterErstellen(@ModelAttribute Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter, Model m)
{
    mitarbeiterRepository.save(mitarbeiter);
    m.addAttribute("AlleMitarbeiter", mitarbeiterRepository.findAll());
    return "showMitarbeiter";
}
```

This is the form HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Neuen Mitarbeiter erstellen</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen}" th:object="${mitarbeiter}" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" required/><br>
    Aufgabe: <input type="text" th:field="*{aufgabe}" required/><br>
    Geschlecht: <input type="text" th:field="*{geschlecht}" required/<br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Neuen Mitarbeiter erstellen"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MitarbeiterRepository extends CrudRepository<Mitarbeiter, Long> {
}
```

```
    PS C:\Users\Test> http POST localhost:8080/Projektmanagement/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen
HTTP/1.1 200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: de-DE
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 30 Jul 2022 16:50:43 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

PS C:\Users\Test> http GET localhost:8080/Projektmanagement/neuerMitarbeiter
HTTP/1.1 200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: de-DE
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 30 Jul 2022 16:52:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

That is the httpie request with POST on the event handler for the post and a get request on the get of the form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Neuen Mitarbeiter erstellen</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" required id="name" name="name" value=""/><br>
    Aufgabe: <input type="text" required id="aufgabe" name="aufgabe" value=""/><br>
    Geschlecht: <input type="text" required id="geschlecht" name="geschlecht" value=""/><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Neuen Mitarbeiter erstellen"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Site Code when you view it in the browser

Comment: Post the html code as html snippet, not an image. Nobody will type it manually...

Comment: "_I have linked a Picture because stackoverflow just prints the html how it looks but not the code dont know why_" - Please do not post images of code. Instead, provide the text, and then [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) it appropriately. You can display your HTML code this way.

Comment: Where is your `@PostMapping(value="/neuesProjektErstellen")` route handler, to match the form's `th:action="@{/neuesProjektErstellen}"`?

Comment: (Small point: code snippets are for _runnable_ HTML/JS/CSS. Your HTML is not runnable, so just use standard code formatting as shown in my previous help link.)

Comment: the route handler is the @PostMapping(value="/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen")
public String neuenMitarbeiterErstellen(@ModelAttribute Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter, Model m)

Comment: That does not match your form - hence my question. Maybe I am missing something obvious here?

Comment: why should that not match my form? the th action is is match by the routehandler and the post is also handled

Comment: Your form sends a POST request to `/neuesProjektErstellen` but where is the handler for that endoint? It's not shown anywhere in the Java code you have presented in the question.

Comment: @PostMapping(value="/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen")
public String neuenMitarbeiterErstellen(@ModelAttribute Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter, Model m)
{
is the route handler it accepts post methods and takes the object created with the form and puts in as an input into the method

Comment: Right - but that does not match your form. Your form is not sending its request to `/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen`. It's sending it to `/neuesProjektErstellen`.

Comment: Change your HTML form to match your Java, or change your Java to match your HTML form.

Comment: ohh sorry wrong method oupsi I changed it

Comment: Did you resolve your `404 - page not found` issue? If so, then I'm glad!

Comment: no I did not I'm still waiting for anwers :(

Comment: 2 more notes: (a) Another minor point: Your HTML code has 2 opening `<html>` tags. There should only be one. (b) Suggestion: Can you show us what the rendered HTML for your form looks like (ie. the HTML as displayed in "view page source" , as opposed to what's in the Thymeleaf template)?

Comment: I added the source code of the side when viewed in the browser and tested only one html tag which is not making a difference

Comment: Most people follow a convention to use lower-train-truck-case for paths.

Comment: The last HTML snipped has `action="/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen"` but your GETs that are working have a context of `/Projektmanagement/neuerMitarbeiter` -- is `th:action="@{/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen}"` not correctly mapping to `action="/Projektmanagement/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen"`?

Comment: Development suggestion: use a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to ensure you're sending the POST to the correct endpoint and to verify your endpoint behaves as expected.  Once you have that working **then** write the front end code.  Such an approach has served my teams well. We use it for database or Elasticsearch queries too: develop the query directly against the resource then implement the query in code.  We also include the native query as a code comment for reference.

Comment: The Problem is that I tested it with httpie and it worked there it showed the site showMitarbeiter and correctly got the post part

Comment: ok I downloaded postman and sended a post request with values and keys and it worked but I dont know why my html form is not working then

Comment: when I do it through the html form post error when I am doing it over postman it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Okay the Answer is that your th:action in the html has to be the function that you want to use and not the route means the slash at th:action="@{/neuenMitarbeiterErstellen}"  must go. thx paul for the software postman that helped me :)